# SDL Window won't pop up

Tags: c++, window, sdl

My window won't pop up.

Console appears, and without opening window just says that "Application ended"

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

SDL_Window * okno;
SDL_Surface * ekran;
SDL_Event zdarzenie;

int frame = 0;

int main(int argc, char*args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    return 0;

    okno = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_TEST", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, NULL);

    ekran = SDL_GetWindowSurface(okno);

}
```

Comment: `return 0;` is your bug. After the return the program ends because `main()` ends. You certainly did not want to end before you called `SDL_CreateWindow`. Did your compiler warn about unreachable code??

Comment: Voting to close as solved in a manner unlikely to help future askers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return 0;` is your bug. After the return the program ends because `main()` ends.  No lines in main are executed after the return. You certainly did not want to end before you called SDL_CreateWindow.

[Can a function continue after a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352254/can-a-function-continue-after-a-return-statement)

Change the code to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

SDL_Window * okno;
SDL_Surface * ekran;
SDL_Event zdarzenie;

int frame = 0;

int main(int argc, char*args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    okno = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_TEST", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, NULL);

    ekran = SDL_GetWindowSurface(okno);

}
```

In `c++` return 0; can be omitted from main.

[Can I omit return from main in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545291/can-i-omit-return-from-main-in-c)

Also I would expect this code to issue a warning (about unreachable code) on many compilers. If it did not warn you may need to turn up the warning level of your compiler. If it did warn you need to pay more attention to the warnings..

You may also want to remove the global variables and instead make your variables local to main. Global variables are usually considered a bad practice.

[Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Also `SDL_Init()` can fail. You may want to check its return value and quit on failure logging the error.

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}
```

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice that return in like 2 days! I know how return works, but I didn't notice it. Anyway, thanks m8!